# Should the operands to a utility always appear after all the options to the utility?

Tags: bash, posix, options

[POSIX says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html)

> ```
> utility_name[-a][-b][-c option_argument]
>     [-d|-e][-f[option_argument]][operand...]
> ```
>
> ...
>   The arguments following the last options and option-arguments are
>   named "operands".

Does it mean that by POSIX standard, the operands to a utility should always appear after all the options to the utility?

Why do some commands or utilities go wrong if running it without following the rule, while others don't? For example:

1. In the manpage of `ls`:

   ```
   SYNOPSIS
          ls [OPTION]... [FILE]...
   ```

   it shows that `[FILE]...` appears after `[OPTION]...`.

   But it seems that the operands can appear before the options. E.g.,
   `ls . -a` works the same as `ls -a .`
2. For bash's builtin `read`, if I specify an option after an operand, 
   it will be wrong:

   ```
   $ read tt -u 5 5 < /tmp/tt
   bash: read: `-u': not a valid identifier 
   $ read -u 5  tt 5</tmp/tt 
   $ echo $tt 
   1 2 3 4 5
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you want your program to be more portable.

Allowing options to appear anywhere among arguments is [GNU specific](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Command_002dLine-Interfaces).

In any case, you can always use `--` to denote end of options, anything after `--` will be considered operands.

Comment: Thanks. My bash is also GNU Bash. Should bash and its builtin commands also follow the GNU specific standards?

Comment: I asked it because `read` is a builtin command of GNU Bash.

Comment: @Tim: no, shell builtins have their own rules. Those only apply for standard utilities.

Comment: (1) What is the definition of standard utilities? what utilities are standard utilities? what are not? (2) what rules do bash builtins follow

Comment: (2) Read https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html (1) Read the Posix standard

Comment: Can you point out the sentence/paragraph/page in POSIX for (1)?

Comment: @Tim: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14

Comment: you link is for shell builtin. But you mentioned read the POSIX standard for the definition of standard utilities.

Comment: @Tim: I mean you should read POSIX standard for list of standard utilities. Any standard utilities can be implemented as builtin, see more here http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tagtcjh_18

Comment: (1) " shell builtins have their own rules. Those only apply for standard utilities. " Do you mean shell builtins and standard utiltiies are mutually exclusive in a shell?  or some standard utilities are builtins and some aren't? (2) "you should read POSIX standard for list of standard utilities". Where is the  "list of standard utilities" in POSIX?

Comment: @Tim: You can read [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_433) for exact definition.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question on the title:

> Should operands appear after options?

Yes.

Do they always?

No.

How a program process options and operands (in general: arguments) is entirely up to the developer of the utility. Some developers follow some general rules, other developers follow other general rules. The two most common general rules are the GNU rules and the POSIX rules.